# How does tox install my poetry project on its virtual environment?

Tags: python, testing, tox, python-poetry

I'm using tox with poetry with pyenv and I'm getting quite confused.

I'm using `pyenv local 3.6.9 3.7.10` to set several python versions in my `myproject`root folder. Above that, I use poetry to manage dependencies and the `mypackage` build. Finally, I use tox to make automatic testings for several python versions.

My problem is that tox creates for - let's say versions 3.6.9 - a virtual environment located in the `myproject/.tox` directory. To that end, it installs all dependencies listed by poetry in that virtual env, but is installs also `mypackage` !!! (I checked in the `.tox` folder.

Questions:

1. tox usually install the packages with pip. Yet, I use poetry here. How can it install my package then? Does it build the wheel with poetry and install it afterwards?
2. Does it update my local directory code on modification? Should I make a `tox -r`?
3. I recently moved my test folder configuration into

```
project.toml
src
  +- mypackage
      +- __init__.py
      +- mypackage.py
tests
  +- test_mypackage.py
```

and, I need to run `pytest` when modifying `mypackage`. How to do that?

4. What's the link with `skipsdist=True`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Usually, on StackOverflow it is common to just ask one question.

Comment: Yes, I the question has to be specific. But in that case, I should have made 4 specific questions. I think this question title resume well my four sub-questions. Sorry community !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ad 1) `tox` does not build a wheel, but an sdist (source distribution). If you wanted to build a wheel, you need to install https://github.com/ionelmc/tox-wheel

But your idea is right. `poetry` builds the sdist, and uses `pip` under the hood to install it.

ad 2) `tox` notices changes of your source code, so no need to do a `tox -r`. The documentation of `tox` lacks a bit info about this topic. Meanwhile, have a look at https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/2003#issuecomment-815832363.

ad 3) `pytest` does test discovery on its own, so it should be able to find the tests. A command like `pytest` or `poetry run pytest` in your case should be enough. Disclaimer: I do not use `poetry`, so maybe you'd need to be a more explicit about the path. The official `poetry` documentation on `tox` suggests the following command: `poetry run pytest tests/`, see https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#is-tox-supported

ad 4) You can read more about `skipsdist=True` at https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-skipsdist - so this tells `tox` whether to build an `sdist` or not. If you do not build an sdist, your tests will not test the built package, but only the source code (if you direct `pytest` to it). This may be not what you want - depending whether you develop an app or a library, or other circumstances I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for all these info. That was clear :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)